# How to change preference title when fragment has its own layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-appcompat

I have preference screen which is set from custom layout. On large screens I can change title on the action bar, but there is another title on the fragment top itself, which is generated automatically (`AppCompatPreferenceActivity`). Which reads "Settings" all the time. How can I change this title it?

This so weird that I cant even find proper name for this in the documentation. Fragment title?

Unfortunately it seems that I cant add a screenshot, I hope this question is understandable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution. I named the section in more general words. And realized it with one fragment with different content depending on intent extra.

As to question itself, it cannot be done.